# Do we have some package or module in django through which we can see real-time changes of our html files in django as we edit the code?

Tags: node.js, django, node-modules

as we have lite-server in Node to monitor real-time changes of our files, do we have anything similar to it in Django?

Comment: See Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56805827/11475846

Comment: PyCharm does that.  But its an IDE not a package.

Comment: Hi @LewisHepburn, the answer explains the concept of ajax that is not what i'm asking. I'm asking is there a package through which we can monitor real time changes as we update code of our files, as lite-server serves the same functionality in node.

Comment: @SyedBilawalHassan I had this issue when I first started. I don't believe there is one out there. Which is why people are lead to separate from Django front-end to JS front-end.

Comment: @RedCricket, Pycharm for sure is an IDE, but i'm not familiar with its real time changes functionality. In node specifically, there exists a module "lite-server" which serves this functionality regardless of IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is a way to live reload(live server).

[This django app](https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server) adds a management command that starts a livereload server watching all your static files and templates as well as a custom runserver command that issues livereload requests when the development server is ready after a restart.

**Installation**

Install package:

```
$ pip install django-livereload-server
```

Add 'livereload' to the INSTALLED_APPS, before `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` if this is used:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'livereload',
    ...
)
```

Add `'livereload.middleware.LiveReloadScript'` to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES (probably at the end):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'livereload.middleware.LiveReloadScript',
)
```

Or to MIDDLEWARE for Django >= 1.10:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'livereload.middleware.LiveReloadScript',
]
```

This will inject the livereload.js script into your webpages if DEBUG setting is on.

Configuration
If you need the livereload server to use a different host and port than the default 127.0.0.1 and 35729, specify them by setting LIVERELOAD_HOST and LIVERELOAD_PORT in settings.py.

Usage
Start the livereload server:

```
$ python manage.py livereload
```

keep the livereload server running.

Start the django development server as usual (in another console):

$ python manage.py runserver
In the browser's address bar access your web app by doing:

127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000
now every time you hit save in your editor, the django-development-server/livereload-server automatically updates the staticfiles

Customization
By default both template and staticfiles directories are watched.

You can ignore template directories using:

```
$ ./manage.py livereload --ignore-template-dirs
```

Or staticfiles directories using:

```
$ ./manage.py livereload --ignore-static-dirs
```

You can ignore file extensions:

```
$ ./manage.py livereload --ignore-file-extensions=.less,.scss
```

Extra files and/or paths to watch for changes can be added as positional arguments. By default livereload server watches the files that are found by your staticfiles finders and your template loaders.

```
$ python manage.py livereload path/to/my-extra-directory/
```

This will be excluded from the paths ignored by --ignore-template-dirs and --ignore-static-dirs.

Host and port can be overridden with --host and --port options.

```
$ python manage.py livereload --host=myhost.com --port=9090
```

the runserver command python manage.py runserver also accepts three additional options:

- `--nolivereload` to disable livereload functionality
- `--livereload-host` to override both default and settings file specified host address
- `--livereload-port` to override both default and settings file specified port