# Django 3.1: StreamingHttpResponse with an async generator

Tags: python, django, server-sent-events

[Documentation for Django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/#async-views:%7E:text=The%20main%20benefits%20are%20the%20ability,long%2Dpolling%2C%20and%20other%20exciting%20response%20types.) says this about async views:

> The main benefits are the ability to service hundreds of connections without using Python threads. This allows you to use slow streaming, long-polling, and other exciting response types.

I believe that "slow streaming" means we could implement an [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) view without monopolizing a thread per client, so I tried to sketch a simple view, like so:

```py
async def stream(request):

    async def event_stream():
        while True:
            yield 'data: The server time is: %s\n\n' % datetime.datetime.now()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    return StreamingHttpResponse(event_stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

(note: I adapted the code from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55522953/1164966))

Unfortunately, when this view is invoked, it raises the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 330, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 38, in inner
    response = await get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 231, in _get_response_async
    response = await wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "./chat/views.py", line 144, in watch
    return StreamingHttpResponse(event_stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 367, in __init__
    self.streaming_content = streaming_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 382, in streaming_content
    self._set_streaming_content(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 386, in _set_streaming_content
    self._iterator = iter(value)
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
```

To me, this shows that `StreamingHttpResponse` doesn't currently support async generators.

I tried to modify `StreamingHttpResponse` to use `async for` but I wasn't able to do much.

Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's not supported as nothing in the response object is `awaitable`.

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon so what is your actual goal? Have some page that generates response chunk-by-chunk (for big response) or have ability to asynchronously send SSE (Server Side Events) when some other event occurs? Or something completely else? Because I see fixed `StreamingHttpResponse` from your question, but you still haven't accepted that response.

Comment: My goal is to send SSE, and I'll accept the first response that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old question but it came up on a Google result since I was looking for a solution to the same issue. In the end I found this repo https://github.com/valberg/django-sse - which uses async views in Django 4.2 to stream via SSE (specifically see [here](https://github.com/valberg/django-sse/blob/7b04c404aa75d4c4e3a70d8b0847905694a95c93/chat/views.py#L67)).

I understand this is a recent addition to Django so I hope it helps anyone else looking for an answer.

Comment: Indeed, [the code](https://github.com/bblanchon/django-sse-demo) that was not working with Django 3.2, now magically works with 4.2. In his repo, valberg went a step further by implementing notification with PostgreSQL, which is excellent. Thanks a lot for sharing this!

Answer (score 5):

Honestly it is not supported natively by Django, but I have a solution for you using Daphne (which is also using in Django channels).

Created own `StreamingHttpResponse` class that is able to retrieve data stream from async methods and provide it to synchronous part of Django.

```py
import asyncio

# By design asyncio does not allow its event loop to be nested.
# Trying to do so will give the error "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running".
# This library solves that problem.
import nest_asyncio

from django.http.response import StreamingHttpResponse


class AsyncStreamingHttpResponse(StreamingHttpResponse):

    def __init__(self, streaming_content=(), *args, **kwargs):
        sync_streaming_content = self.get_sync_iterator(streaming_content)
        super().__init__(streaming_content=sync_streaming_content, *args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    async def convert_async_iterable(stream):
        """Accepts async_generator and async_iterator"""
        return iter([chunk async for chunk in stream])

    def get_sync_iterator(self, async_iterable):
        nest_asyncio.apply()

        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        result = loop.run_until_complete(self.convert_async_iterable(async_iterable))
        return result
```

Also, you'll need to run your Django web-server using [Daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne) to support Server Sent Events (SSE) properly. It is officially support by "Django Software Foundation" and has similar syntax to `gunicorn`, but uses `asgi.py` instead of `wsgi.py`.

To use it - you can install using: `pip install daphne`

And change command from: `python manage.py runserver`
to something like: `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 sse_demo.asgi:application`.

Not sure if it will work with `gunicorn`.

Let me know if you'll have any more questions.

Comment: sorry to ask, what does `SSE` stand for?

Comment: In code this is just a naming (idea from authors question), can be changed. But I believe it is about `Server Sent Events`. Will rename class from `SSEResponse` to `AsyncStreamingHttpResponse` to make it more clear for others.

Comment: Thanks, @wowkin2.  
I tried to use this class but got `ValueError: loop argument must agree with Future`.  
 [Here is the source code of the view](https://github.com/bblanchon/django31-sse-demo/blob/f3a1faa79cb3d8eef51e4b0c3073b6d7eb42d4b1/clock/views.py); can you check?

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon forgot to mention, you need to run django with `daphne` to use async and Server Sent Events. Added more details to answer, but here is the command to check: `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 sse_demo.asgi:application`

Comment: I just tried with daphne, and it doesn't seem to work. `curl -N 127.0.0.1:8000` doesn't show anything and the daphne process gets stuck and doesn't even respond to `Ctrl-C`.

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon here is my full code in this repository: https://github.com/wowkin2/django-test-streaming-response

Comment: Thanks, @wowkin2, but it's still not working. I opened a few issues, please check.

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon answered to all of them.

Comment: Please tell me if I'm wrong, but since the generator never ends, `loop.run_until_complete()` will block forever, right?

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon it will only not allow you to stop script using `Ctrl+C` (if you will not check for that signal in generator explicitly). It will not block anything else. Please better describe what you want to achieve using StreamingHttpResponse or SSE. Because here I just helped you to fix StreamingHttpResponse not solve your problem (about which I have no idea, perhaps you even don’t need SSE ir SHR)

Comment: I think I've been pretty clear, look at the top of this page: "I'm giving 200 reputation to the first person who finds the right way to do SSE with an async view in Django 3.1+".

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon sending webbooks is also SSE (server sent event), but has nothing with async :) That’s why you need to explain your goal better. Send what, to where, how often, how big amount of data, what data type, and etc.

Comment: "Server-Sent Events is a standard describing how servers can initiate data transmission towards clients once an initial client connection has been established." ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events)). I don't think you can include webhooks in it.

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon there you can find library [django-eventstream](https://github.com/fanout/django-eventstream) for that on wiki page. And it uses Django Channels (which was also recommened by @Adrien).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do SSE is to use special library [`django-eventstream`](https://github.com/fanout/django-eventstream):

Add following to HTML page that will consume data:

```html
<script src="{% static 'django_eventstream/eventsource.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'django_eventstream/reconnecting-eventsource.js' %}"></script>

var es = new ReconnectingEventSource('/events/');

es.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    console.log(e.data);
}, false);

es.addEventListener('stream-reset', function (e) {
    // ... client fell behind, reinitialize ...
}, false);
```

For backend you'll need to [properly setup Django](https://github.com/fanout/django-eventstream#setup-with-channels), and later you'll be able to call following method in any view/task/signal/method that needs to do Server Side Event (SSE):

Add following view that will produce data (events):

```py
# from django_eventstream import send_event

send_event('test', 'message', {'text': 'hello world'})
```

Comment: `django-eventstream` relies on Django Channels and doesn't leverage the new async views of Django 3.1.

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon agree, anyhow you can call that from any async view. Or you can use pure Django Channels that should utilize it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a decorator named `stream` that can be used with a coroutine function to make it compatible with Django's `StreamingHttpResponse`. Here's an example:

```py
import asyncio
import functools

from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse


def stream(coroutine_function):
    @functools.wraps(coroutine_function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        coroutine = coroutine_function(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            while True:
                yield asyncio.run(coroutine.__anext__())
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            pass
    return wrapper


@stream
async def chunks():
    for char in 'Hello, world!':
        yield char
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def index(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(chunks())
```

I also needed to add `nest_asyncio` and call `apply()` at the top of the `settings.py` file like:

```py
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

The `nest_asyncio` dependency supports calling `asyncio.run` from the `wrapper` function created by the `stream` decorator.

Finally, Django's `asgi` can be run using `uvicorn` through `gunicorn` like:

```
$ gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker www.asgi:application
```

Comment: I have an issue runnig this with uvloop

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have to use something like [django-channel](https://github.com/django/channels) :

> Channels augments Django to bring WebSocket, long-poll HTTP, task
> offloading and other async support to your code, using familiar Django
> design patterns and a flexible underlying framework that lets you not
> only customize behaviours but also write support for your own
> protocols and needs.

Comment: Thanks for this response @Adrien, but this doesn't answer the question. I know about Django channels, but I want to know if we can avoid it now that Django 3.1 supports async views.