# Can we fetch real time data with rest api in DRF if yes please tell me what steps we need to perform?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, real-time

I want to build a listing API that returns the most recent data without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326515/how-can-i-make-sse-with-python-django) should work for you. Or [this](https://github.com/fanout/django-eventstream). Or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63452601/12914274).

It's all the solutions that fit your questions.

Comment: Please post relevant details form the links you included, such as a summary or example code.  Link only answers are discouraged, since the source may be removed and they require people to follow links to get relevant context.

Comment: Since I have no feedback from the author and the question gained low interest from the community, I'm afraid it's not worth the time. In fact, I also didn't find it as interesting; I just wanted to help the OP with the direction. If it wasn't helpful for the OP, I feel like deleting my answer is the best way. As an experienced community member, what would you advise me to do in this situation? And what would you've done in such a situation?