# How to sends custom status messages to the front end when the endpoint has some heavy process time, if I am using Django as backend?

Tags: python, django, next.js, frontend, backend

this is a very general question. I was trying to look for something but here I might have a better start point. I am working with a python tool which is still on progress but the UI was done previously with PYQT5. What I wanted to do is creating some web front end (NextJs) and connecting with Django as backend and the calculations will be done on the local server we have.

What I wanted to check is how I can send real time updates to the front end about the process that is happening on the backend. lets say if there is a loop, so sending the 1/10,2/10 and so on. Is this a socket thing (?) like streaming messages while is inside the http request.

Thank you!

I am still on the looking for options stage, what I have though is that this can be possible with sockets and emit messages from the backend to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) to create a socket and a socket library like [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) for NodeJS to form a connection to send/receive data.

Then just handle them in your NextJs frontend.

Since you are just sending and not receiving, a unidirectional method like SSE (server sent events) can be used too. However, it comes with it's own set of issues (see below).

[How can I make SSE with Python (Django)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326515/how-can-i-make-sse-with-python-django)

I would recommend sticking with Channels or if you have the time, take a look at [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse).

Comment: Thanks! for the referrals. I will take a look for sure.